# Can't find my extension on Chrome webstore

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I uploaded a new extension, 2 days ago, to and I can't find it in Chrome webstore.

I can access the extension only with the direct link.

Any idea ?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The extension appeared in chrome webstore 3 days later so I guess it is matter of time.